# How to use Counter enabled loop processing of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named **creative_db** Table name is **store_weblinks**. Now inside this table there are several columns that holds the entire site's weblinks. My focus is on this column - **weblinks_status**

Now weblinks_status contains 2 values = **waiting** and **live**

So here's what I intend to do - Update any 10 waiting to live status.

I think I need a loop of some kind that would keep a count of how many successful edits are taking place. Once that hits 10 it will stop processing..

So, its like this -- Check if the current item of weblinks_status is waiting. If it is waiting then change it to live and increment the loop counter else proceed to the next waiting item..

Need your help!

Comment: You don't need a loop. You just need a LIMIT

Answer (score 2):

Try this STATEMENT:

```
UPDATE store_weblinks 
SET weblinks_status="live" 
WHERE weblinks_status="waiting" 
LIMIT 10;
```

This should work to update any 10 entries from waiting to live.

Comment: I ran this query but nothing is happening :( no error codes no change in the database.

Comment: Did you run the query directly in your sql database or with PHP?  If you ran it with PHP you could try outputing sql errors with this function [mysql-error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) . If you have any entries that would get updated but do not then you should get a sql error that will help.